# Forking a network to simulate events

Tags: contract-development, javascript, events, blocks

I'm trying to simulate an event by forking a network. For example:

```
    wss.on('block', async (blockNumber) => {
    // Your code here
});
```

How can I accomplish this? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!